# How to use D3 to append several html line of codes

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js

I need to add all this code by using D3:

```
 <fieldset style="width: 280px; margin-left: 45px; position: absolute;" >
        <legend>Options</legend>
          <d>Rotation: </d>&nbsp;
          <select id="rotation" style="position: center;">

          </select>  &nbsp; 
          <d>Inclination: &nbsp;</d>
          <select id="inclination" style="position: center;">

          </select>
     </fieldset>
```

The reason why I need D3 is that I want to add this snippet of code only after a certain task has been completed and only afterwards I want to populate the two `Select` elements.

How can I do that? Thank you very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `d3.html()`.

Just start by selecting the outlet where you want the controls to be placed, and then use the html method to insert them.

```
d3.select('#where-you-want-the-output').html('<fieldset style="width: 280px; margin-left: 45px; position: absolute;" ><legend>Options</legend><d>Rotation: </d>&nbsp;<select id="rotation" style="position: center;"></select>  &nbsp; <d>Inclination: &nbsp;</d><select id="inclination" style="position: center;"></select></fieldset>');
```

And if you want to keep the formatting in your source code, you can use `\` to make a multi-line string.

```
d3.select('body').html(
'<fieldset style="width: 280px; margin-left: 45px; position: absolute;" > \
  <legend>Options</legend> \
    <d>Rotation: </d>&nbsp; \
    <select id="rotation" style="position: center;"> \
 \
    </select>  &nbsp; \
    <d>Inclination: &nbsp;</d> \
    <select id="inclination" style="position: center;"> ]
 \
    </select> \
</fieldset>');
```

If you provide an argument to `d3.html` it will set the html for that selection, but if you call it without an argument, it will *return* what's already there.  So, if you have existing content you can pull it as a string like this...

```
d3.select('#where-i-want-to-add-more-content').html(
  d3.select('#where-i-want-to-add-more-content').html() + // get what's already there...
  '<fieldset style="width: 280px; margin-left: 45px; position: absolute;" > \
    <legend>Options</legend> \
      <d>Rotation: </d>&nbsp; \
      <select id="rotation" style="position: center;"> \
   \
      </select>  &nbsp; \
      <d>Inclination: &nbsp;</d> \
      <select id="inclination" style="position: center;"> ]
   \
      </select> \
  </fieldset>'
);
```

...although, at this point, it's arguably getting a little messy, and you might be better off having a specific container for the message that you're okay overwriting the contents of every time.  Or using `d3.append` to build your output programmatically.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes it does its job... the problem is that everything contained in `'#where-I-want-the-output'` gets overwritten... is there a way to preserve it?

Comment: You can put an empty element in place to act as the outlet -- for example, make `#where-i-want-the-output` be a hidden div inside where you _actually_ want the output.  Or you can use `d3.append` to build your controls.

Comment: _Or_ you can use `d3.html` to grab the current contents, and prepend that in front of your string.  I'll update the example to illustrate...